# Access Javascript variables dynamically

Tags: javascript

I know you might think this is a duplicate or a dumb question. But the answers doesn't help me.

Here's my simple problem:

```
var option1 = "some text";
var option2 = "some text";
var option3 = "some text";
```

I want to access the elements "option1, option2, option3" in a for loop:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    alert(option+i);   
}
```

I know that it shouldn't be option+i but I dont know how to solve this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

If you find this to be a duplicate just mark this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
    option = new Array();
    option[1] = "some text";
    option[2] = "some text";
    option[3] = "some text";
    for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        alert(option[i]);   
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If they are variables in the `window` scope, then you can access `window['option'+i]`. However, you really should just use an array:

```
var option = [
    "some text",
    "option 2",
    "option 3"
];
for( var i=0; i<3; i++) alert(option[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var option1 = "some text";
var option2 = "some text";
var option3 = "some text";

for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
 alert(eval('option'+i) + '\n');
}
```

It's better if you try and use an array or access it via `window` as Kolink posted. And if you do use `eval`, make sure nothing that is not in your control gets `eval`'ed as its a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

change your loop to look like this:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    alert(eval("option"+i));   
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I have a question: Are you crazy? This is probably the worst use of `eval` I have ever seen, and I've seen some pretty bad stuff...

Comment: It works, but... it rhymes with "evil." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: @Kolink thank you for your feedback.  This is a silly, simple problem to begin with.  I upvoted your answer its a more fundamentally stable approach.  I am not crazy

Comment: var x = ['text1','text2','text3']; for (var i =0; i< x.length; i++) { console.log(x[i]); }