# How to concatenate variable inside function name?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have this code:

```
var a = 1;

function test + a() {
    alert('test');    
}

test1();
```

I've received this error from the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +
```

So how can I concatenate the variable `a` to `test` which finally run function `test1` here?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbmd67mq/)**

Comment: Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515924/access-javascript-variables-dynamically , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826154/can-i-create-dynamic-object-names-in-javascript?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291554/dynamic-variables-names-in-javascript

Comment: Simply assign the function to a *given* "dynamic variable name". But better: use an explicit array/object and map the functions to indices/properties.

Answer (score 4):

In javascript, all variables/methods declared globally are members of the object `window`, so you can declare the function this way:

```
var a = 1;

window['test' + a] = function() {
    alert('test');    
}

test1();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbmd67mq/1/)

*PS - There are very few situations where you should be doing something like this. If you're unsure, please edit your question. There might be a better way of achieving what you want than using dynamically named functions attached to the global window object. Just because it can be done doesn't mean it should be.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var a = 1;
var name="test"+a;
var func = new Function(
     "return function " + name + "(){ alert('test');    }"
)();
//function call
func();
```